If a function is $1$-periodic then it writes as a holomorphic function of $e^{2 \pi i z}$
I want to prove the following proposition:

Suppose that $g \in H(\mathbb{H})$ (where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane) and $g(z+1) = g(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{H}$. Then there exists a function $G \in H(\mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\})$ such that $g(z) = G(e^{2 \pi i z})$.

I don't know how to solve / start this. I thought that I can find a branch of logarithm, but in $\mathbb{D} \setminus \{0\}$ there isn't one...

So you want to map each line of constant real part to a radius of the disk and each line of constant imaginary part to a circle centered at zero on the disk.  And you want to arrange that the real translation by $1$ corresponds to rotating the disk by $2\pi$...  Why do you think you need a branch of the logarithm?

@EricTowers I've seen this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213832/1053101  but I don't understand why function defined by Sanghchul Lee is well-defined

Where does $\log z$ send lines of constant real part and lines of constant imaginary part?  In order to be well-defined, you will have to adapt the $z \mapsto z+1$ periodicity to the periodicity of the images of the lines of constant imaginary part (by scaling and/or translating the inputs and outputs of $\log z$).

@EricTowers well.. I don't understand why are you trying to explain to me :( can you give me your solution please?

The principle branch of logarithm is defined for all non-zero complex numbers but it is not analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus {0}$. So Sangchul Lees's definition does make sense, and it is not hard to prove well-definedness and analyticity in this case.

@geetha290krm principle branch of logarithm is not defined on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{-}$ ?

Let $q:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ by $q(z) = e^{2\pi iz}$. This is easily seen to be surjective and holomorphic. Since $e^{2\pi iz} = e^{2\pi iw}$ iff $z = w + n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, in this case $g(z) = g(w)$. Thus there exist unique function $G:\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g = G\circ q$, in other words $g(z) = G(e^{2\pi iz})$.
Now since $q'(z) = 2\pi ie^{2\pi iz}\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{H}$, by the inverse function theorem of complex analysis, it has local inverse everywhere. That is, for each $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that $q:U\to q(U)$ is bijective, and the inverse $p:q(U)\to U$ is holomorphic. Then we see that on $q(U)$, $G = G\circ (q\circ p) = g\circ p$ is holomorphic. Since each $q_0\in\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ is an image of $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$ under $q$, it is in $q(U)$ for some $U$ as above, and we see that $G$ is holomorphic everywhere. This completes the proof.

This needs proofreading.

I discovered this proof by myself, so if anyone find something absurd, please let me know.

Why "there exists unique function $G : \mathbb{D} \setminus {0} \to \mathbb{C}$" ?

It is set theoretic stuff. We define $G$ by the equation $G(q_0) = g(z_0)$, where $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$ satisfies $q_0 = q(z_0)$. Since $q$ is surjective, any $q_0\in\mathbb{D}\setminus{0}$ is of the form $q(z_0)$ for some $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$, and we can define $G$ on whole domain $\mathbb{D}\setminus{0}$. Moreover for any two $z, w\in\mathbb{H}$ with $e^{2\pi iz}=e^{2\pi iw}$, we have $g(z) = g(w)$, so that the value of $G$ does not depend on which $z_0$ we choose. Moreover, if $g = G\circ q$, then this would be the only possible choice, as $q_0 = q(z_0)$ forces $G(q_0) = g(z_0)$.

Also I initially forgot to define $q$, and I just added it.
